# How to extract topics or hashtags followed by a user using Tweepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

Is there an existing function or class in Tweepy that allows getting a list of accounts followed by a user, Twitter topics, and hashtags used in tweets?

Also, I would like to know, if such functionality doesn't exist, what is the ideal or best way to implement it using Python and scraping libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For accounts followed by a user, you can use [`API.friends`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#tweepy.API.friends) or [`API.friends_ids`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#tweepy.API.friends_ids).
If you want to use v2 of Twitter's API, you can currently use [`Client.get_users_following`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html#tweepy.Client.get_users_following) with the development version of Tweepy on the master branch.

Twitter's API doesn't currently support retrieving followed Topics, and I'm not sure what you mean by hashtags followed by a user, as following a hashtag isn't possible.

Comment: Thanks, @Harmon758. Can you guide me about the 2nd part of the question where I asked if no such functionality exists, what is the best way to implement it using scraping?

Comment: Scraping Twitter itself without using its API violates its [Terms of Service](https://twitter.com/en/tos), so no, I can't do that for you.

Comment: cool. thanks, @Harmon758 . I'll go through the terms of service more carefully now